# No route matches [PATCH] "/posts/my-second-post"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error an UPDATE to an existing post on the Blog app (Rails):

I changed `author_posts_path` to `author_post_path` when I was getting an error

> No route matches [PATCH] "/posts/my-second-post"

Now, I'm getting a new error as follows:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Blog::Posts#index
>
> Showing C:/Users/Royal and Carla/Desktop/testBlog3c/app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb where line #18 raised:
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"author/post"}, missing required keys: [:id]

views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb

```
16     </li> 
17        <li class="nav-item">
18        <%= link_to 'My posts', author_post_path, class: "nav-link #
          {yield(:author)}" %>
19     </li>   
20    </ul>
21  </div>
```

ontrollers/author/posts_controller.rb

```
private
      def set_post
        @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
      end      
    
      def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :description, :banner_image_url)
      end
```

Comment: Can show your `routes.rb` file

Answer (score 0):

It seems to to be you not passing the post object id if your `routes.rb` file looks like this

```
namespace :author do 
  resources :posts
end
```

then run the `rake routes` then you will get output looks like this

```
    author_posts GET    /author/posts(.:format)          author/posts#index
                 POST   /author/posts(.:format)          author/posts#create
 new_author_post GET    /author/posts/new(.:format)      author/posts#new
edit_author_post GET    /author/posts/:id/edit(.:format) author/posts#edit
     author_post GET    /author/posts/:id(.:format)      author/posts#show
                 PATCH  /author/posts/:id(.:format)      author/posts#update
                 PUT    /author/posts/:id(.:format)      author/posts#update
                 DELETE /author/posts/:id(.:format)      author/posts#destroy
```

See this

```
edit_author_post GET    /author/posts/:id/edit(.:format) author/posts#edit
     author_post GET    /author/posts/:id(.:format)      author/posts#show
                 PATCH  /author/posts/:id(.:format)      author/posts#update
                 PUT    /author/posts/:id(.:format)      author/posts#update
```

you need to `:id` for `edit`, `update` & `show` if need edit then your edit link looks like this

```
edit_author_post_path(post_object_id) # object_id is a post.id
```

then update `form_tag` will looks like this

```
form_for [:author, @post] do |f|...
```

It should work, hope it will helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Here is my route file: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  

  root to: 'blog/posts#index'

  namespace :author do
    resources :posts
  end

  scope module: 'blog' do
    get 'about' => 'pages#about', as: :about
    get 'contact' => 'pages#contact', as: :contact
    get 'posts' => 'post#index', as: :posts
    get 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show', as: :post    
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end

Comment: I checked my files and I don't see the form tag you mentioned.

Comment: Please describe your question how update the existing post, I'm writing an answer for you

Comment: Not sure I understand?

Comment: I found this in my _form.html.erb: <%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

Answer (score 0):

you want to update post,first you need a edit view and in this view request update action.
so I think you first step change link path to edit_author_post(@post)